# Error received "No best type found for implicitly-typed array"

Tags: c#, json, implicit

This is my code for creating Json response for jqGrid and for **new** keyword for defining cell member I receive following message "No best type found for implicitly-typed array".

```
var resRows = results.Select(record => 
            new 
            {
                id = record.Reference,
                cell = **new** []
                {
                    record.Reference,
                    record.TradeDate.ToShortDateString(),
                    record.Currency1,
                    record.Currency2,
                    record.Notional.ToString(),
                    record.EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString(),
                    record.Quote.ToString()                        
                }
            }).ToArray();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `Reference`, `Currency1` and `Currency2` are strings, just declare it as a string array:

```
var resRows = results.Select(record => 

    new 
    {
        id = record.Reference,
        cell = new string []
        {
            record.Reference,
            record.TradeDate.ToShortDateString(),
            record.Currency1,
            record.Currency2,
            record.Notional.ToString(),
            record.EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString(),
            record.Quote.ToString()                        
        }
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: @D Stanley, I did it and it works! Actually, if these were not strings, I could just use `cell = new object [] {... }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare data for jqGrid (like in your code), you can define your own jsonReader and just skip the cell array (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data):

```
jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        userdata: "userdata"
    },
```

Then something like:

```
var result = new
{
    total = (int)count / grid.PageSize),
    page = grid.PageIndex,
    records = count,
    rows = results.Select(record => 
                    select new
                    {
                        Reference = record.Reference,
                        TradeDate = record.TradeDate,
                        ..
                     }).ToArray()
}
```

Comment: Replace "select new" to "new"

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found that if all data items in the array were of the same type (example String) then the type was inferred and the compiler didn't complain about **new[]**.

Answer (score 0):

If the members of the collection are functions, it still gives the compiler error.  Even if there is only **one** function in the collection!

```
var bads = new []  // COMPILER ERROR
{
    Foo
};

var goods = new Action[]  // NO COMPILER ERROR
{
    Foo
};

//...
public void Foo() { }
```